# Read all bytes of an image and store in a byte array using C

Tags: c++, c, image, filesystems

I'm working on evolis primacy printer (Card Printer) and UNIX-SCO-OpenServer 5.0.7. I'm developing a program in c that open a socket and send command through socket to the printer.

I should to place some text and image on a PVC card and then print it.
and now I developed first section of code in Java that:

1. get parameter from command line
2. generate text according to parameters
3. place all of them in it's position
4. generate an png file and save it to disk

Now I need another program that load the image bytes into an array of bytes (byte[] variable_name) to send it to the printer through socket.

My socket program is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#define INVALID_SOCKET -1
#define SOCKET_ERROR -1
#define closesocket(s) close(s)
typedef int SOCKET;
typedef struct sockaddr_in SOCKADDR_IN;
typedef struct sockaddr SOCKADDR;
typedef struct in_addr IN_ADDR;
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#define PORT 9100       // the port client will be connecting to 
#define MAXDATASIZE 10240 // max number of bytes we can get at once 

char* ipdest;
int sockfd, numbytes;  
char buf[MAXDATASIZE];

struct hostent *he;
struct sockaddr_in their_addr; // connector's address information 
struct in_addr addr;


unsigned char[] load_file(char* filename){
    unsigned char[] file_data=NULL;
    //FILL file_data FROM FILE BYTES
    return file_data;
}
void send_command(char* command, unsigned char* data[]){
    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr,sizeof their_addr) == -1) {
        perror("connect");
        exit(1);
    }
    if(data != NULL){
        //MERGE DATA AND COMMAND AND THEN
        //sprintf(buf,"\033%s\015", command);
    }
    else
        sprintf(buf,"\033%s\015", command);
    if (send(sockfd, buf, strlen(buf)+1, 0) == -1) {
        perror("send");
        exit(1);
    }
    shutdown(sockfd, 1);
    if ((numbytes=recv(sockfd, buf, MAXDATASIZE-1, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("recv");
        exit(1);
    }
    buf[numbytes] = '\0';
    printf("Received: %s\n",buf);
    closesocket(sockfd);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr,"printer ip address not defined!!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    ipdest = argv[1];
    if ((!isalpha(ipdest[0])) || (he=gethostbyname(ipdest)) == NULL) 
    {
        addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ipdest);
        if (addr.s_addr == INADDR_NONE) 
        {
            printf("The IPv4 address entered must be a legal address\n");
            return 1;
        } 
        else
        he = gethostbyaddr((char *) &addr, 4, AF_INET);
    }   
    if (he==NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to open %s\n", ipdest );
        exit(1);
    }
    if ((sockfd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    their_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;    
    their_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);  
    their_addr.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *)he->h_addr);
    memset(their_addr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof their_addr.sin_zero);

    //LOAD FILE AND SEND IT'S DATA TO PRINTER
    send_command("Stt",load_file("res.png"));

    return 0;
}
```

I've a method named it: load_file() that should load file bytes, but how?
And after loading file and passing it's data to send_command method I should to merge it's data with my command explained in code.

Comment: PNG you say? You're going to need an image in `bitmap` format (easy to read without libraries) OR a library like libPNG, ImageMagick, etc.. to read it.

Comment: Perhaps off topic, but I'm looking for the documentation of the SDK for the Evolis Primacy. I'm guessing the asker has it. Where can I find this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you don't know yet how your card printer works so I think you should know first how the PNG format is supported. You can do so if there's a manual, an API, or an open source driver for your type of printer. Once you know how, you can use the following load_file code and then create another "transform" code that will transform the simple byte array from load_file.

load_file:

```
FILE *fp;
fp= fopen("res.png", "rb");    
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);         
length= ftell(fp);           
rewind(fp);             
file_data= (char *)malloc((length+1)*sizeof(char));
fread(file_data, length, 1, fp);
return file_data
```

send_command:

```
if(data != NULL){
    //do the transformation here
    transform(data);
}
```

Comment: thank you,i know how it works,and now i know that it can print bitmap only,thans a lot ;)

Comment: Oh ok. No problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Pointer here instead of "unsigned char []" and you can pass the same to  "send_command " once it is filled